# Can I travel to the UK later than the start date of my visa?

Tags: indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas

I'm an Indian with an Indian passport, planning to apply for a Standard Visitor visa to UK.

Once I have my visitor's visa approved, can I make my travel plans anytime within that approved time frame?

I saw the maximum time to start my visa application is 90 days before my travel date. For instance, I apply now for the visitor's visa stating March 31st, as my travel date in my application, but I really don't travel on March 31st, instead I travel on July 15th.

Would UK Immigration allow me into the country?

Here is my scenario: I apply For UK visitor's visa now, once it gets approved I would like to travel to USA for three months (I already have a USA visitor's visa) and on my way back I would like to spend in UK for a week (my cousin invited me to stay).

So, I'm not sure with that "90 day rule" I can travel to UK after the date I mentioned in the application.

If that's not an option what are my other options?

Comment: You have the UK confused with Schengen's 90 day rule. There's no such rule in the UK. In theory, you can come and go as you like until your entry clearance expires.  The issuing post can forward date your entry clearance up to 3 months from the application date. That may be the source of your confusion.  So your plan as described above is fine.  You need to tell the issuing post to forward date your visa.

Comment: @GayotFow that is an answer I guess, do you think there can be a better one?

Comment: @skv I think it's an answer. You (or anybody else) wanting to claim some rep are invited to tart it up and create a formal answer.  I left it there for that purpose...  It's encouraged!

Comment: @GayotFow thanks for you reply! What is "Issuing post"? and I think it is not Schengen's rule, it seems like it is UK's rule as well. Please see that in this link in Step 3 http://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/india/how_to_apply.html

Comment: I think @GayotFow thinks that your question has to do with staying more than 90 days in the UK in a 180 day period, when the 90/180 rule is a Schengen rule that does not apply to the UK.

Comment: @UKTraveller, "issuing post" = the post that issued the visa. Normally a British Consulate General, but any mission authorized to issue visas.  And 'phoog' is right, you have the two concepts wired up incorrectly.

Comment: @GayotFow Thank you both for your replies! Essentially what you both are saying is I can apply for the visitors visa now(in January'16) and have the visa approved, and I can make my travel arrangements in July'16. is that right? Can you also please help me understand what the Step 3 in this link http://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/india/how_to_apply.html really means? especially this sentence "You can apply for a visa up to 3 months before your date of travel to the UK" and how it might effect my travel(if it does)? I still don't clearly understand. Thanks for being so patient and appreciate the help!

Comment: @GayotFow Could you please reply me? I'm not sure what that really means and should I book my vacation as per my plan. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

There is no requirement in the UK on when you must enter once you have your visa, it appears you're confusing this with Schengen rules. Once your UK visit visa is granted, you can visit (in theory) as you like within the validity period of the visa.

As Gayot Fow suggested, simply request the British mission issuing your visa to forward date your visa